# nohup not starting mono

Tags: bash, process, nohup, mono

### What I've done

I have a home server where I test scripts before deploying them on a remote server. The script does some checks and at the end it starts a *mono* process in the background, using *nohup* to avoid hungup signals.

```
# ... processing of some files

nohup mono ${executable_file} ${data_file} ${password} > ${log_file} &
echo "A new mono instance will start shortly"

exit 0
```

### The problem

At my local machine I can *pgrep* the mono process but on the remote server the process does not start (`pgrep mono` returns nothing). What I've noticed is that typing the same command directly in the console actually starts mono process.

**ps**: I've seen some people advising the use of `screen` instead of `nohup` but that's not an option in my case.

Comment: There's no `nohup.out` because I am redirecting it to `log.txt`. I don't know what exactly *running the script directly* means but I can tell you if type the command directly in the terminal it works. If not the process does not start. @TomYan

Comment: So anything in log.txt? What I meant is, did you "type the name of the script directly in terminal" when it does not work?

Comment: On my home server I do get output in `Log.txt` from a dumb mono process I have. On the remote server the log file probably contains nothing since the process does not even start.

Comment: About *typing the command directly* the answer is no. I've created more abstract script, placed it in `/usr/local/bin`, the script mentioned in the question placed it in `/usr/local/lib`. What I do is calling the more abstract script as a command and passing an argument to call the script mentioned in the question, like `abstract_script --call-other-script`. But it does get called...